# On hover display another div using Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a section in which on hover on a parent div I want to display a children div (element) , so here is

JSFIDDLE:[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xevtd96b/4/)

Here is HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="box">1
        <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">2
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">3
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
  <div class="box">4
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
  <div class="box">5
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
  <div class="box">6
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    console.log('init') 
    $('.box').hover(function(){     
        $('.box-children').addClass('open');    
    },     
    function(){    
        $('.box-children').removeClass('open');     
    });
});
```

EXPECTED:

On the hover parent element, it should display the children element

Unfortunately now on hover, it displays all children element
[image]

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/wjcdpo0b/ ? `$('.box-children',this)` -> `this` refers to the `.box` you have clicked on and that will search for `.box-children` inside `this`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes exactly dude that was hella quick !!! holy shit

Comment: Why wouldn't you add this as an answer?

Comment: @0stone0 Well I could but I'm not always a fan about copying code from fiddle to SO and there will most likely be someone else posting the answer. As you can see someone else just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make use of 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events and toggle required CSS classes to show / hide children div. Use `this` to find the correct children div.

See below code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    console.log('init');
    //hide all children on page load
    $('.box-children').addClass('close');
    $('.box').on('mouseenter', function(){  
        $(this).find('.box-children').toggleClass('open close');    
    });     
    $('.box').on('mouseleave', function(){    
        $(this).find('.box-children').toggleClass('open close');      
    });
});
```

```css
.open {display: block;}
.close {display: none;}
.box {border: 1px solid red;}
.box-children {border: 1px solid green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="box">1
        <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">2
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">3
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
  <div class="box">4
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
  <div class="box">5
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
  <div class="box">6
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` in a callback to reference the trigger element (in this case, the parent):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    console.log('init') 
    $('.box').hover(function(){     
        $(this).find('.box-children').addClass('open');    
    },     
    function(){    
        $(this).find('.box-children').removeClass('open');     
    });
});
```

```css
.box-children {
  display: none;
}

.box-children.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="box">1
        <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">2
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">3
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
  <div class="box">4
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
  <div class="box">5
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
  <div class="box">6
          <span class="box-children">Children Div</span>

  </div>
</div>
```